# flutter Black screen when trying to log in using firebase backend

Tags: flutter, dart

When I log in, the screen stays black https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOHap.jpg and it says please wait and it just stays like that. When I signed up it did the same but when I checked firebase console I saw that the account I created was registered on firebase authentification user. My MacBook Pro fan seems to make noise when the screen is black while showing “Please wait..” And loading.

How can I fix this issue and make it go to home page after signing in?

Also when I tried to write;

```
user = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
email: email, password: password);
```

Without as FirebaseUser at the end it won’t allow me, 
but this used to work. I thought maybe it doesn’t work because of this.

```
user = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
email: email, password: password) As Firebase;
```

Firebase file

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:projectname/tools/app_methods.dart';
import 'app_tools.dart';
import 'app_data.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io'; 
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class FirebaseMethods implements AppMethods {
Firestore firestore = Firestore.instance;
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

@override
Future<String> createUserAccount(
  {String fullname, String phone, String email, String password}) 
async {
// TODO: implement createUserAccount
FirebaseUser user;

try {
  user = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email, password: password) as FirebaseUser;
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  //print(e.details);
  return errorMSG(e.details);
}

try {
  if (user != null) {
    await 
firestore.collection(usersData).document(user.uid).setData({
      userID: user.uid,
      acctFullName: fullname,
      userEmail: email,
      userPassword: password,
      phoneNumber: phone
    });

    writeDataLocally(key: userID, value: user.uid);
    writeDataLocally(key: fullname, value: fullname);
    writeDataLocally(key: userEmail, value: userEmail);
    writeDataLocally(key: userPassword, value: password);
  }
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  //print(e.details);
  return errorMSG(e.details);
}

return user == null ? errorMSG("Error") : successfulMSG();
}

@override
Future<String> logginUser({String email, String password}) async {
// TODO: implement logginUser

FirebaseUser user;
try {
  user = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email, password: password) as FirebaseUser;

  if (user != null) {
    DocumentSnapshot userInfo = await getUserInfo(user.uid);
    await writeDataLocally(key: userID, value: userInfo[userID]);
    await writeDataLocally(
        key: acctFullName, value: userInfo[acctFullName]);
    await writeDataLocally(key: userEmail, value: 
userInfo[userEmail]);
    await writeDataLocally(key: phoneNumber, value: 
userInfo[phoneNumber]);
    await writeDataLocally(key: photoURL, value: 
userInfo[photoURL]);
    await writeBoolDataLocally(key: loggedIN, value: true);

    print(userInfo[userEmail]);
  }
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  //print(e.details);
  return errorMSG(e.details);
}

return user == null ? errorMSG("Error") : successfulMSG();
}

Future<bool> complete() async {
return true;
}

Future<bool> notComplete() async {
return false;
}

Future<String> successfulMSG() async {
return successful;
}

Future<String> errorMSG(String e) async {
return e;
}

@override
Future<bool> logOutUser() async {
// TODO: implement logOutUser
await auth.signOut();
await clearDataLocally();

return complete();
}

@override
Future<DocumentSnapshot> getUserInfo(String userid) async {
// TODO: implement getUserInfo
return await firestore.collection(usersData).document(userid).get();
}
}
```

App tools

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'progressdialog.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

Widget appTextField(
{IconData textIcon,
String textHint,
bool isPassword,
double sidePadding,TextInputType textType,
TextEditingController controller}) {
sidePadding == null ? sidePadding = 0.0 : sidePadding;
textHint == null ? textHint = "" : textHint;
//textType == null ? textType == TextInputType.text : textType;

return Padding(
padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: sidePadding, right: sidePadding),
child: new Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.white,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
  ),
  child: TextField(
    controller: controller,
    obscureText: isPassword == null ? false : isPassword,
    keyboardType: textType == null ? TextInputType.text : textType,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: InputBorder.none,
        hintText: textHint,
        prefixIcon: textIcon == null ? Container() : Icon(textIcon),
       ),
     ),
   ),
 );
}

Widget appButton({String btnTxt, double btnPadding, Color btnColor, 
VoidCallback onBtnclicked}) {
btnTxt == null ? btnTxt == "App Button" : btnTxt;
btnPadding == null ? btnPadding = 0.0 : btnPadding;
btnColor == null ? btnColor = Colors.black : btnColor;

return Padding(
padding: new EdgeInsets.all(btnPadding),
child: RaisedButton(
  color: Colors.white,
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0))),
  onPressed: onBtnclicked,
  child: Container(
    height: 20.0,
    child: Center(
      child: Text(btnTxt, style: TextStyle(color: btnColor, 
        fontSize: 18.0),),
      ),
     ),
    ),
   );
  }

  showSnackBar(String message, final scaffoldKey) {
  scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
  backgroundColor: Colors.red[600],
  content: new Text(
   message,
  style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
 ),
 ));
 }

displayProgressDialog(BuildContext context) {
Navigator.of(context).push(PageRouteBuilder(
  pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, _, __){
    return ProgressDialog();
  }));
}

closeProgressDialog(BuildContext context) {
Navigator.of(context).pop();
}

writeDataLocally({String key,String value}) async {
Future<SharedPreferences> saveLocal = 
SharedPreferences.getInstance();
final SharedPreferences localData = await saveLocal;
localData.setString(key, value);
 }

writeBoolDataLocally({String key, bool value}) async {
Future<SharedPreferences> saveLocal = 
SharedPreferences.getInstance();
final SharedPreferences localData = await saveLocal;
localData.setBool(key, value);
}

clearDataLocally() async {
Future<SharedPreferences> saveLocal = 
SharedPreferences.getInstance();
final SharedPreferences localData = await saveLocal;
localData.clear();
 }
```

App method file

```
import 'dart:async';

abstract class AppMethods{
Future<String> logginUser({String email, String password});
Future<String> createUserAccount(
 {String fullname, String phone, String email, String password});

 }
```

Login file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:projectname/tools/app_data.dart';
import 'package:projectname/tools/app_tools.dart';
import 'package:projectname/userScreens/signup.dart';
import 'package:projectname/tools/app_methods.dart';
import 'package:projectname/tools/firebase_methods.dart';


class Login extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_LoginState createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {

TextEditingController email = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController password = TextEditingController();
final scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
BuildContext context;
AppMethods appMethod = FirebaseMethods();


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
this.context = context;
return Scaffold(
  key: scaffoldKey,
  backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
  appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Login"),
    centerTitle: false,
  ),
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
        appTextField(isPassword: false, sidePadding: 18.0,
            textHint: "Email Address",
            textIcon: Icons.email,
            controller: email),
        SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
        appTextField(isPassword: true,
            sidePadding: 18.0,
            textHint: "Password",
            textIcon: Icons.lock,
            controller: password),
        appButton(
          btnTxt: "Login",
            onBtnclicked: verifyLoggin,
            btnPadding: 20.0,
            btnColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: (){
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignUp()),
            );
          },
          child: Text(
            "Not Registered? Sign Up Here",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),),
      ],
    ),
  ),
 );
}

verifyLoggin() async {
if (email.text == "") {
   showSnackBar("Email cannot be empty", scaffoldKey);
   return;
 }

 if (password.text == "") {
    showSnackBar("Password cannot be empty", scaffoldKey);
    return;
  }

 displayProgressDialog(context);
 String response = await appMethod.logginUser(
      email: email.text.toLowerCase(), password: 
 password.text.toLowerCase());
 if (response == successful) {
   closeProgressDialog(context);
   Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
  } else {
   closeProgressDialog(context);
   showSnackBar(response, scaffoldKey);
  }

}

}
```

Sign Up file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:projectname/tools/app_data.dart';
import 'package:projectname/tools/app_methods.dart';
import 'package:projectname/tools/app_tools.dart';
import 'package:projectname/tools/firebase_methods.dart';

class SignUp extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_SignUpState createState() => _SignUpState();
}

class _SignUpState extends State<SignUp> {

TextEditingController fullname = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController phoneNumber = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController email = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController password = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController re_password = TextEditingController();
final scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
BuildContext context;
AppMethods appMethod = FirebaseMethods();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
this.context = context;
return Scaffold(
  key: scaffoldKey,
  backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
  appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Sign Up"),
    centerTitle: false,
  ),
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
        appTextField(isPassword: false, sidePadding: 18.0,
            textHint: "Full name",
            textIcon: Icons.person,
            controller: fullname),
        SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
        appTextField(isPassword: false, sidePadding: 18.0,
            textHint: "Phone Number",
            textIcon: Icons.phone, textType: TextInputType.number,
            controller: phoneNumber),
        SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
        appTextField(isPassword: false, sidePadding: 18.0,
            textHint: "Email Address",
            textIcon: Icons.email,
            controller: email),
        SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
        appTextField(isPassword: true,
            sidePadding: 18.0,
            textHint: "Password",
            textIcon: Icons.lock,
            controller: password),
        SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
        appTextField(isPassword: true,
            sidePadding: 18.0,
            textHint: "Re-Password",
            textIcon: Icons.lock,
            controller: re_password),
        appButton(
            btnTxt: "Create Account",
            onBtnclicked: verifyDetails,
            btnPadding: 20.0,
            btnColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
      ],
    ),
   ),
 );
}

verifyDetails() async {
if (fullname.text == "") {
  showSnackBar("Full Name cannot be empty", scaffoldKey);
  return;
}

if (phoneNumber.text == "") {
  showSnackBar("Phone Number cannot be empty", scaffoldKey);
  return;
}

if (password.text == "") {
  showSnackBar("Email cannot be empty", scaffoldKey);
  return;
}

if (password.text == "") {
  showSnackBar("Password cannot be empty", scaffoldKey);
  return;
}

if (re_password.text == "") {
  showSnackBar("Password cannot be empty", scaffoldKey);
  return;
}

if (password.text != re_password.text) {
  showSnackBar("Passwords don't match", scaffoldKey);
  return;
}

displayProgressDialog(context);
displayProgressDialog(context);
String response = await appMethod.createUserAccount(
    fullname: fullname.text,
    phone: phoneNumber.text,
    email: email.text.toLowerCase(),
    password: password.text.toLowerCase());

if (response == successful) {
  closeProgressDialog(context);
  Navigator.of(context).pop();
  Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
} else {
  closeProgressDialog(context);
  showSnackBar(response, scaffoldKey);
   }
  }
}
```

The message it gives me when I run

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone Xʀ in debug mode...
[{"event":"app.progress","params":{"appId":"55426b4f-235e-4941-99d9- 
06be21a45fcd","id":"0","progressId":null,"message":"Running Xcode 
build..."}}]Running Xcode build...

Xcode build done.                                           14.1s
Configuring the default Firebase app...
Configured the default Firebase app __FIRAPP_DEFAULT.
[{"event":"app.progress","params": 
{"appId":"numbers","id":"1","progressId":null,"message":"Syncing 
files to device iPhone Xʀ..."}}]Syncing files to device iPhone Xʀ...

[C1.1 C0E2BA03-numbers 192.numbers:numbers<->numbers:443]
Connected Path: satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0
Duration: 0.764s, DNS @0.003s took 0.016s, TCP @0.021s took 0.034s, 
TLS took 0.138s
bytes in/out: 4612/1077, packets in/out: 11/9, rtt: 0.033s, 
retransmitted packets: 0, out-of-order packets: 0
6.5.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000004] App with name __FIRAPP_DEFAULT 
does not exist.
6.5.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.60004000 
started
6.5.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging 
set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled 
(see https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/dev3ec8a1cb4)
[C2.1 numbers <->numbers]
Connected Path: satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0
Duration: 0.573s, DNS @0.000s took 0.007s, TCP @0.011s took 0.040s, 
TLS took 0.068s
bytes in/out: 5686/999, packets in/out: 11/9, rtt: 0.032s, 
retransmitted packets: 0, out-of-order packets: 0
[C3.1 ECnumbers numbers<->numbers]
Connected Path: satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0
Duration: 0.297s, DNS @0.000s took 0.003s, TCP @0.006s took 0.022s, 
TLS took 0.062s
bytes in/out: 5262/1841, packets in/out: 10/9, rtt: 0.020s, 
retransmitted packets: 0, out-of-order packets: 0
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: type 
'AuthResult' is not a subtype of type 'FirebaseUser' in type cast
#0      FirebaseMethods.logginUser 
(package:projectname/tools/firebase_methods.dart:58:45)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      _LoginState.verifyLoggin 
(package:projectname/userScreens/login.dart:79:39)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      _InkResponseState._handleTap 
(package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:635:14)
#3      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> 
(package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:711:32)
#4      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback 
(package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
#5      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp 
(package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:365:11)
#6      TapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer 
(package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:275:7)
#7      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent 
(package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:455:9)
#8      PointerRouter._dispatch 
(package:flutter/src/gestures/pointe<…>
```

my pubspec.yaml

```
firebase_auth: ^0.14.0
cloud_firestore: any
google_sign_in: ^4.0.6
shared_preferences: ^0.5.3+4
http: ^0.12.0+2
image_picker: ^0.6.1
firebase_database:  ^3.0.5
firebase_storage: ^3.0.5
```

Comment: Please clarify your question and show what you did, to solve the issue. A quick look shows, that the method you use `auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword` does not return a FirebaseUser but an AuthResult, thats also what is written in your logs.

Comment: when I log in, the screen stays black (image showing the screen https://imgur.com/a/2qaeGox ) but I want to actually be able to enter the app and be able to use the app as someone who has loggen in.

Comment: @Eknoes instead of;   user = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);    ...which is AuthResult, what should it be?

Comment: The logfile you provided says so: `'AuthResult' is not a subtype of type 'FirebaseUser' in type cast
#0      FirebaseMethods.logginUser 
(package:projectname/tools/firebase_methods.dart:58:45)`. I would recommend you looking at [How to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and maybe [How to debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You expect an `FirebaseUser` but get an `AuthResult`, which can provide a [FirebaseUser](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/AuthResult-class.html).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code it's just that Firebase_auth changed the way to implement it. I changed my firebase_auth dependency to firebase_auth: ^0.5.14 and this code works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Base from the logs, it looks like the cause of the issue is a type mismatch. It's likely that you're casting the result of `auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword` with a mismatching type.

```
'AuthResult' is not a subtype of type 'FirebaseUser' in type cast
```

The auth result should return a [UserCredential](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/UserCredential-class.html) that you can use. Also, instead of casting `as FirebaseUser` on the auth result, fetch the **user** to avoid typecasting issues. `User` has replaced `FirebaseUser` since firebase_auth 0.18.0

```dart
UserCredential? userCred; 
User? user;

userCred = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email, password: password);

user = userCred.user;
```